# Unlock windows phone - Check Microsoft account credentials

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am attempting to unlock my Microsoft Lumia 640 LTE for development.
OS: Windows Phone 8.1 Update 2

I have a developer account and normal Microsoft account (both are using the same email as username).

Once I start the phone registration tool, after signing in I encounter this problem:

Error logging into Windows Phone Dev Center. Check your Microsoft account credentials and try again.

[image]

Comment: I reset the phone, plugged it into a different hub and it works..

Comment: Same phone, same OS, same issue. Restarting the phone worked for me, without resetting or changing the HUB.

Comment: What might be different - my "official" (and original) location is Slovakia, but since I wanted to try out cortana I specified US region..

Anyhow, after the factory reset (and subsequent changing of the USB hub which I ofc. do not find important) it worked - again with US region.